# How to Setup Jndi with weblogic server

Tags: java, tomcat7, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

I am new to weblogic server.I have setup JNDI with tomcat server and it runing fine for me .But i have to setup JNDI with weblogic so please anyone help me where i have put

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/myPath" name="jdbc/myPath"
        type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
```

This code i.e in tomcat i have put this code in `Context.xml` file but not know where to add this in weblogic and this code also:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myPath" auth="Container"
            type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory" url="url"
            user="username" password="password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
            maxWait="10000" />
```

This code is in server.xml file of tomcat but not know where to put in weblogic.Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Use weblogic console for this purpose. Login to the console and then click Data Sources.

Comment: i am using on local where i can login from local?

Comment: localhost:7001/console

Answer (score 2):

You go to `http://localhost:7001/console/`. The default credentials are weblogic/welcome1. Then you access the data sources section and create your data source.

Comment: ok now i am there in DatasSource.Can you please provide the next step to setup JNDI in Weblogic

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/CreateDataSources.html

Comment: Take a read through the docs linked in the prior comment. On Tomcat you can edit the server config files directly, but that's not advisable on Weblogic - config is only done via the web-based Console app (or alternatively can be automated via the Weblogic Scripting Tool)